push notification: Error 3000 Issue with 'aps-environment' during App Center build
I'm facing an issue during the app build process on App Center. When I build the application using Xcode on my local device, I don't encounter this problem (I have another issue, which is why I was trying to build on App Center). However, when I try to build the app on App Center, I receive the error "Error 3000: no valid 'aps-environment' entitlement string found".
Here's what I've already tried:

I created a new provisioning profile after enabling push notifications.
I included the .entitlements file with the aps-environment key in my project. The content of the file is as follows:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>aps-environment</key>
    <string>production</string>
</dict>
</plist>


In my provisioning profile, there is a string: aps-environment configured correctly.
The bundleId of the application is correct.
i created a new mobileprovisioning after enabling push notifications
i have checked that the provisioning is the same on xcode and appcenter

I have carefully checked the build logs of App Center, but I can't find any specific indication of what might be causing this issue.
The problem seems to be specific to the build on App Center, as it doesn't occur when I build and test the app locally with Xcode.
Can you suggest what else I could try to solve this problem?
